# Why is the vector space of a representation of the cyclic group $C_2$ a direct sum?

Tags: representation-theory

In [Representation theory: Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9OsEZV5YX8?t=941) Richard Borcherds gives the example of $\mathrm{G} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{1, g\}$. He says that a (complex) vector space $V$ is the direct sum $V = V^+ \oplus V^-$ because any vector can be written as:

$$
v = \frac{v + gv}{2} + \frac{v - gv}{2}.
$$

I would like to understand why $v_+ := \frac{1}{2}(v + gv)$ form a subspace $V^+$. This confuses me since $v_+$ depends on $v$ but the subspace $V^+$ cannot depend on $v$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to GL(V)$ be a representation. As $\phi(g)^2 = \phi(g^2) = \phi(1) = \operatorname{id}$, we see that $\phi(g)$ is diagonalisable with two possible eigenvalues, namely $1$ and $-1$. The splitting $V = V^+\oplus V^-$ is just the eigenspace decomposition where $V^{\pm}$ is the eigenspace of $\pm 1$. Explicitly, we can describe the subspaces by $V^{\pm} = \ker(\operatorname{id} \mp \phi(g))$; note that $v \in V^{\pm}$ if and only if $\phi(g)(v) = g\cdot v = \pm v$.

If $v \in V$, then $v = v^+ + v^-$ where $v^{\pm} \in V^{\pm}$. Then $g\cdot v = g\cdot v^+ + g\cdot v^- = v^+ - v^-$, so we see that $v^+ = \frac{1}{2}(v + g\cdot v)$ and $v^- = \frac{1}{2}(v-g\cdot v)$ which gives the decomposition of $v$ you provided.

An example you may have seen before is the case where $V$ is the vector space of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action is generated by $f \mapsto g\cdot f$ where $(g\cdot f)(x) = f(-x)$. In this case, $V^+$ consists of even functions and $V^-$ consists of odd functions. Any function $f$ can be written as the sum of an even function $f^+$ and an odd function $f^-$ where $f^{\pm}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x) \pm f(-x))$.

Comment: I am happy you included the 3rd paragraph as well, thank you.